# FullArmor ADMX Editor: Does it work correctly/well for admx files?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, windows-registry

I am currently creating some admx files. I found the FullArmor ADMX Migrator from Microsoft which also includes an ADMX editor. However, when using this editor I found the outputs quite strange. For example it was not possible to create a PolicySetting that sets a Value through a TextBox. You can create a new PolicySetting but you always have to include an enabled/disabled value as these xml elements are always created.

Am I doing something wrong or have you made a similar experience? Is there an alternative?